# Fix backup with Anaconda2 as primary Python Shell

Tags: python, backup, duplicity, anaconda

The default backup app doesn't work properly.

I searched in the web and my Anaconda2 seems to be the problem but I still want it as my primary Python.

If I run in the console:

```
duplicity --version
```

The output is:

```
File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 61, in <module>
    from duplicity import log
ImportError: No module named duplicity
```

How can I fix it and still use Anaconda2 as my primary python shell?

Comment: @alfred-m  It would be useful to know what version of duplicity you have installed. since `duplicity --version ` isn't working, the command `dpkg -l duplicity
` can usually provide the same information.

Comment: Actually with recent updates it seems to work.

Comment: `dpkg -l duplicity` would return this:
`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  duplicity      <none>       <none>       (no description available)`

Comment: after do apt-get install duplicity, `duplicity --version` return this: `duplicity 0.7.06`

It seems that the updates fixed the problem, but anyways, I tried to update and reinstall duplicity before and didn't work like now.

Comment: I run dplicity 0.7.06 and still get this error.

Comment: Add the contents of `/usr/bin/duplicity` to your question, please.

Answer (score 3):

`duplicity` is a Python script that lives at `/usr/bin/duplicity` and the error given indicates a problem at line 61 of the script. Opening it in your favorite text editor and navigating down to line 61 might provide some clues. I'm running `duplicity 0.6.23` on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and `duplicity 0.7.06` on Ubuntu 16.04.3 and in both cases line 61 of the script is blank and I cannot reproduce this error.

It's possible that you can simply edit the script to resolve the problem, commenting out line 61, or re-installing duplicity, however if [Duplicity and Anaconda clash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964642/duplicity-and-anaconda-clash) is an accurate assessment of the problem you could run duplicity under a different account and insure that the path for **that** account includes  /usr/bin BEFORE your Anaconda folder. More details on account specific  $PATH adjustment can be found in the answers [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

Comment: Removing anaconda from the path (namely, using system python) solves the problem. I wonder why Anaconda's python does not suit duplicity and how I could have the two live together.

Comment: @AlfredM. You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-do-i-tell-a-python-script-to-use-a-particular-version) useful.