# Duplicity and Anaconda clash

Tags: python, duplicity, anaconda

Trying to use `duplicity` on ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda 2 installed, raise the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 61, in <module>
    from duplicity import log
ImportError: No module named duplicity
```

Removing the Anaconda folder from my `$PATH` solve the issue (it uses vanilla python, `which python` yields `/usr/bin/python`).

How to solve this issue without tampering with environment variables every time?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has something to do with the administrator privileges. I managed to use it by `sudo duplicity`, and could then run some related programs like deja-dup.

Comment: that's because `sudo` uses its own `secure_path` (given in the sudoers file). But this probably isn't a good solution - running applications with root privileges might have unintended effects